# 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to convert a Tensor to a numpy array.
The tensor i have has a shape as below

```
LastDenseLayer.output.shape
TensorShape([None, 128])
```

When i am running the code as below,

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    LastLayer = LastDenseLayer.output.eval()
```

getting the below error

- module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'

I am running Keras model and trying to get the values of a specific layer out of that.

Unable to understand that is wrong here.

Regards
Sachin

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow 2.x removed `tf.Session` because eager execution is now a default. Please refer to the [TensorFlow migration guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#1_replace_v1sessionrun_calls) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to update your code to meet Tensorflow 2.0 requirements. As a quick solution you can use `tf.compat.v1.Session()` instead of `tf.Session()`:

```
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    LastLayer = LastDenseLayer.output.eval()
```